# Fixed Sticky Element for Blogger - Stop Before Footer?

Tags: jquery

I've been searching for hours for help with this so I am hoping someone can lend a hand. :)  I have a sticky/fixed div at the bottom of my sidebar, but need it to stop sticking when it reaches the footer div. First of all, I realize there are other questions relating to this and I have tried them countless times but they are not working and I have no idea how to implement them with this particular code for Blogger. This code is currently the only one I could get to work properly on my blog with Blogger's formatting. Please help??

```
bs_makeSticky("HTML18"); 
function bs_makeSticky(elem) {

    var bs_sticky = document.getElementById(elem);
    var scrollee = document.createElement("div");
    bs_sticky.parentNode.insertBefore(scrollee, bs_sticky);
    var width = bs_sticky.offsetWidth;
    var iniClass = bs_sticky.className + ' bs_sticky';

    window.addEventListener('scroll', bs_sticking, false);

    function bs_sticking() {
        var rect = scrollee.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (rect.top < 120) {
            bs_sticky.className = iniClass + ' bs_sticking';
            bs_sticky.style.width = width + "px";
        } else {
            bs_sticky.className = iniClass;
        }


    }
}
```

Here is my fixed class:

```
.bs_sticking {
background:#fff !important; 
position:fixed !important; 
top:0; 
margin-top: 120px; 
position:relative\9 !important;
}
```

How do I make it stop sticking at a div called "footer"? thank you.

Comment: Could you give it a bottom margin that is the same height as your footer?

Comment: I tried that, using both bottom-margin and bottom, didn't do anything.